# How to properly use extended constraints on a LEFT JOIN so as to return all results on the left side

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm having trouble converting my budget summary view from last year to this year. Here is the SELECT statement for last year's view which returns things proper:

```
SELECT 
    b.Category AS Category,
    b.Amount AS Amount,
    SUM(e.Amount) AS Spent,
    (b.Amount - SUM(e.Amount)) AS Remaining
FROM 
    Budget AS b LEFT JOIN Expenditure AS e 
    ON (
        b.Category = e.BudgetCategory
        AND e.Date < '2016-01-01'
        AND e.Date > '2015-01-01'
        AND b.Year = 2015
    )
GROUP BY e.BudgetCategory
```

If I edit the dates so that it encompasses this year, then it breaks the view since there are no records in the Expenditure table that are of this year. It only returns the first record from Budget and the fields relying on Expenditure are NULL. What I want is for all records from Budget to be returned and to list NULL for all fields related to those records that depend on Expenditure.

What last year's view returns:

```
Category    | Amount    | Spent     | Remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------
Contractors | 0.00      | NULL      | NULL (this is correct)
Gasoline    | 250.00    | 240.00    | 10.00
Merchandise | 2000.00   | 1900.00   | 100.00
```

etc...

What it's returning for this year:

```
Category    | Amount    | Spent | Remaining
--------------------------------------------
Contractors | 4000.00   | NULL  | NULL
```

What I want it to return (while Expenditure results remain 0):

```
Category    | Amount    | Spent | Remaining 
--------------------------------------------
Contractors | 4000.00   | NULL  | NULL 
Gasoline    | 300.00    | NULL  | NULL 
Merchandise | 2500.00   | NULL  | NULL
```

etc...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `Category` a unique key (maybe the primary key) of table `Budget`? Or can there be several `Budget` records for the same `Category`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate by the columns in the *first* table of a `left join`:

```
SELECT b.Category AS Category, b.amount,
       SUM(e.Amount) AS Spent,
       (b.Amount - SUM(e.Amount)) AS Remaining
FROM Budget b LEFT JOIN
     Expenditure e 
    ON b.Category = e.BudgetCategory AND
       e.Date < '2016-01-01' AND
       e.Date >= '2015-01-01'
       b.Year = 2015
GROUP BY b.Category, b.amount;
```

Small changes:

- I changed the condition in the `ON` clause to `>=`.  It just seems more reasonable.
- I added `b.amount` to the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I found that the query also works by grouping by e.BudgetCategory and b.Category or just b.Category alone. I originally grouped by e.BudgetCategory since things from the e table are being summed. What's a high level explanation of the logic going on here. Why does the group by need to be on whatever side of the join it is?

Comment: @Shadouts: This is because you outer join the Expenditure table. If no match is found in that table for a Budget.Category in the given date range, you get a dummy record with *all* fields NULL, including BudgetCategory. So you didn't group by the category you were actually looking up (Budget.Category).

Comment: @Shadouts: As to "grouping by e.BudgetCategory and b.Category or just b.Category alone", this is because there is only *one* record per category in a year, as you said in a comment to my answer. If this weren't the case you'd get one of the category's amounts arbitrarily chosen. Gordon couldn't know that category + year are unique in your table, so he put budget.amount in the GROUP BY clause to make sure not to silently introduce such an error. Moreover having this column in GROUP BY guarantees that the query even runs with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode switched on in MySQL; it wouldn't otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a minor error. Instead of grouping by `b.Category` you are mistakenly grouping by `e.BudgetCategory`.

```
SELECT 
    b.Category AS Category,
    b.Amount AS Amount,
    SUM(e.Amount) AS Spent,
    (b.Amount - SUM(e.Amount)) AS Remaining
FROM 
    Budget AS b LEFT JOIN Expenditure AS e 
    ON (
        b.Category = e.BudgetCategory
        AND e.Date < '2016-01-01'
        AND e.Date > '2015-01-01'
    )
WHERE b.Year = 2015
GROUP BY b.Category;
```

I moved the criteria on `b.Year` to `WHERE` for readability, because it is no criteria for the outer join of `Expenditure`.

Is `Category` a unique key for table `Budget` by the way? Otherwise you are getting one of the category's amounts arbitrarily chosen. Maybe you'd rather want an aggregate, such as `SUM(b.Amount)` instead.

Comment: b.Amount is a total budget cap, sum(e.amount) is the sum of all money spent from that category. b.Category is unique from year to year, but e.BudgetCategory is a sort of foreign relationship to b.category.

Comment: Ah, okay, then everything's fine. You get one budget record per category for year 2015, so there is no ambiguity as to the amount.